# Titanium - Get height of current window

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium

Is it possible to get the height of the current window as pixel value?
Or alternatively, the screen height as pixel value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For window height you can use **Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight**
You can also try  method
 `view.getRect().height`  or `view.toImage().height`  to get the view height.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks Suraj. I got it working with both view.toImage().height and Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight. For some reason view.getRect().height didn't work on a scrollableView. Thanks again, this was a great help!